# how to create a button in the Listview input tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Alright so i have a UL which implements http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/ . The user types in and the results are suggested as an autocomplete feature .

```
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Input here...." data-filter-theme="a" >
</ul>
```

Now **what i want is** : After the results are suggested as a "Reveal" option , the user can select it . Once the selection is made the selected option becomes a button in the "input" part of the above UL.

something like this :[image]

forbid me for my bad css knowledge . i have no idea about how to do this . I tried setting the `val()` of input . But it seems that val() can only set text not as an HTML. So `$("#input").val("Hey")` would be correct but `$("#input").val("<a href="#" class="ui-btn">Hey</a>")` . Will also be rendered as text .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can not add html to an input.

You have to mask it with a div or something that must not be an input.

The idea: Hide your input when an option selected. Wrap it (input) with a div that looks like an input. Add the selection to that wrapper div.

Something like this:

```
var $input = $('#input-wrapper > input');
var $selections = $('#input-wrapper > #selections');

$('#options > li').click(function(){
    var $new_selection = $('<li />').text($(this).text());
    $selections.append($new_selection);

    $input.val($input.val() + ', ' + $(this).text());

    $('#debugger > #input-value').text($input.val());
});
```

See full code and test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/1h46f8qw/

Answer (score -1):

did u try append method

```
$("#input").append("<a href='#' class='ui-btn'>Hey</a>")
```

or

```
$("#input").html("<a href='#' class='ui-btn'>Hey</a>")
```